# How can I check if the elements of one array are in another?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays one is fix to be 8 letters and the other depends on the user. I have to take user input and put in an array (done) but I need to check if the users input (it is a word) letters are in the other array ? how can I do it ?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Take a look at [this section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Data:-Arrays) of the Perl FAQ which covers much about Perl array manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Perl's (v5.10+) smartmatch operator `~~` to check if a string is an element of an array.  The matching is case-sensitive:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = map lc, qw/This is a test/;

print 'Enter a word: ';
chomp( my $entry = <> );

print qq{The word "$entry" is}
  . ( lc $entry ~~ @words ? '' : ' not' )
  . ' in @words.'
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a word: This
The word "This" is in @words.
```

Comment: and what if I do not use 5.10 or bigger. I have 5.8.8

Comment: @PavelMalinov If `@words` is short, you can use `grep` instead of the smart match. For larger words list, `first` from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) should be more efficient

Comment: @memowe - Good suggestions.  Another option is to `use Syntax::Keyword::Junction qw/any/;` and then `any(@words) eq lc $entry`.

Comment: @PavelMalinov - memowe gave good suggestions.  Another option is to use the [Syntax::Keyword::Junction](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/Syntax-Keyword-Junction-0.003001/lib/Syntax/Keyword/Junction.pm) Module.

Comment: @memowe - I will defently have a look need to make sure i understand it at first before even trying of doing it :) thank you guys